# Convert code c++ to c# , read to a class

Tags: c#, c++

I have a class

```
class DataqFmt 
{
public:
    unsigned short  SR_number;
    unsigned short  SR_numerator;
    unsigned char   offset;
    unsigned char   nbytes;
    short       hdr_bytes;
    unsigned long   dat_bytes;
        char        dummy[1144];
};
```

code c++ :

```
afl = fopen(path, "rb");
DataqFmt dataqstr;
fread ((char*) &dataqstr, sizeof (dataqstr), 1, afl);
```

How can i convert this code c++ to c# . Please help me

Comment: If you need it to work with existing files that has been binary-dumped from C++ in that format, that'll be tricky....

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the C++ application that wrote this file was compiled for Win32 x86 and run on Win32 x86. This allows me to make assumptions about that way that `DataqFmt` was arranged. If these assumptions are wrong, you can adjust them by using the various options of [`StructLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and related attributes, like [`MarshalAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FieldOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, we're going to use a C# structure with the same layout as `DataqFmt`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DataqFmtCs
{
    public ushort SR_number; // assuming the C++ type unsigned short is 2 bytes
    public ushort SR_numerator;
    public byte offset; // assuming the C++ type unsigned char was an unsigned and 1 byte
    public byte nbytes;
    public short hdr_bytes; // assuming the C++ type short was 2 bytes
    public uint dat_bytes; // assuming the C++ type unsigned long was 4 bytes
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1144)]
    public sbyte[] dummy; // assuming the C++ type char was signed and 1 byte
}
```

With that structure, we now need to do file I/O to get the raw bytes.

```
int dataqfmtSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataqFmtCs));
var buffer = new byte[dataqfmtSize];
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("path\\to\\the\\file")) {
    int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead != buffer.Length) {
        // handle this
    }

    DataqFmtCs someThing = GetDataqFmtFromBuffer(buffer);
}
```

Finally, we have the conversion routine `GetDataqFmtFromBuffer`.

```
private static DataqFmtCs GetDataqFmtFromBuffer(byte[] buffer) {
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try {
        return (DataFmtCs)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
            handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
            typeof(DataFmtCs));
    } finally {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

[`Marshal.PtrToStrucutre`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is doing the vast majority of the conversion work. The rest of the code is just defining the struct and doing basic .NET file I/O.

Another option--and this is often a good solution if you are working with a well-documented protocol that is platform agnostic, as you'll often need to perform [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) conversions--is to write a deserialization routine that operates on a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using a [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio you could also import the C++ code and compile it into a CLR library to be referenced by any other .net assembly.  This is especially a good idea if you need the C++ code to run fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to acknowledge that the C++ fread() is inherently fragile and non-portable, it might be better to write an abstraction layer to read (and write) the code data types, for example a format like this is useful:

```
// returns true on success, false on EOF
public static bool Read(Stream stm, out int val)
{ /* ... */ }

public static bool Read(Stream stm, out short val)
{ /* ... */ }
```

then you can write you code to be something like:

```
if (!Read(stm, out _someMember))
    throw SomeException(); // or return a fail code
if (!Read(stm, out _someOtherMember))
    throw SomeException();
```

or in the case of some of my code, I wrote a method that given an object, a stream, and the name of either a field or a property, reads the appropriate sized value and sets the member (or throws an exception if it can't find it), and then a similar method that works on an object and a collection of names (or really a variable number of string arguments, so initialization can look like this:

```
    public static TTHorizontalHeader FromStream(Stream stm)
    {
        TTHorizontalHeader header = new TTHorizontalHeader();
        if (!Reader.ReadType(stm, header,
            "TableVersion", "Ascender", "Descender", "LineGap", "AdvanceWidthMax", "MinLeftSideBearing",
            "MinRightSideBearing", "XMaxExtent", "CaretSlopeRise", "CaretSlopeRun", "CaretOffset", "Reserved0",
            "Reserved1", "Reserved2", "Reserved3", "MetricDataFormat", "NumberOfHMetrics"))
            return null;
        return header;
    }
```

but you say, "won't the C++ run faster since it just does one fread()?" And I reply, "Endianess, data type size, structure padding, and changes in object layout are reason enough to not keep propagating the same fragile code under the guise of performance.  Any decent buffered stream is going to do only one actual read anyway and the reading work is done by an impartial robot.  Besides the cost of I/O, buffered or not, will dwarf the cost of reflection and string iteration.